Vue3 poor man's store
So I am trying to use vue's composition api to create a simple store, but whatever I do, it doesn't work right for some reason.
in store.mjs I have very simple code:
export const testString = ref("abc");
export const testObject = reactive({ abc: 1, xyz: 2 });

Problem is that wherever I import them, they are not reactive.
I also tried to wrap them in a function like pinia does:
export default function useStore(){
   return { testString, testObject }
}


Would you please share, how you use it?

This should work as a use-case for setting and accessing the abc and xyz values of the reactive value.


const { createApp, ref, reactive, watchEffect } = Vue;

const state = reactive({ abc: 1, xyz: 2 });
const testString = ref('My Title');

createApp({
  setup() {
    const handleAbcInput = () => {
      console.log("abc updated to: ", state.abc);
      if (isNaN(state.abc) || state.abc < 0) {
        state.abc = 0;
      }
    };
    const handleXyzInput = () => {
      console.log("xyz updated to: ", state.xyz);
      if (isNaN(state.xyz) || state.xyz < 0) {
        state.xyz = 0;
      }
    };

    watchEffect(() => {
      console.log("Current value of abc: ", state.abc);
    });
    watchEffect(() => {
      console.log("Current value of xyz: ", state.xyz);
    });

    return { testString, state, handleAbcInput, handleXyzInput };
  }
}).mount("#app");
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ testString }}</h1>
  <p>({{ state.abc }}, {{ state.xyz }})</p>
  <input v-model="state.abc" @input="handleAbcInput">
  <input v-model="state.xyz" @input="handleXyzInput">
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>



You can also compute the values, and handle validation:


const { createApp, ref, reactive, computed } = Vue;

const state = reactive({ abc: 1, xyz: 2 });
const testString = ref('My Title');
const validationMessage = ref('');

createApp({
  setup() {
    const validateInput = (value) => {
      const num = +value;
      if (isNaN(num)) {
        validationMessage.value = 'Input must be a number';
        return 0;
      }
      validationMessage.value = ''; // clear message on valid input
      return num;
    };
  
    const abc = computed({
      get() {
        return state.abc;
      },
      set(value) {
        state.abc = validateInput(value);
      }
    });

    const xyz = computed({
      get() {
        return state.xyz;
      },
      set(value) {
        state.xyz = validateInput(value);
      }
    });

    return { testString, abc, xyz, validationMessage };
  }
}).mount("#app");
.err-msg { color: red; }
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ testString }}</h1>
  <p>({{ abc }}, {{ xyz }})</p>
  <input v-model="abc">
  <input v-model="xyz">
  <p class="err-msg" v-if="validationMessage">{{ validationMessage }}</p>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>



